# how to generalize from `File` to `Read`?

Tags: rust

I have some working code that reads a file, but I need to generalize it to pull data from additional sources other than simple disk files.

1. Is `Read` the correct generalization I should work with in order to replace `File`?
2. If so, how can I fix `example2` in the following sample code?  As is, it fails with the compile error `dyn async_std::io::Read cannot be unpinned` at the commented line.  If not, what type should I return instead from `get_read` and are there any corresponding changes required in `example2`?

```
//! [dependencies]
//! tokio = { version = "1.0.1", features = ["full"] }
//! async-std = "1.8.0"
//! anyhow = "1.0.32"

use async_std::io::prelude::*;
use async_std::fs::File;
use anyhow::Result;

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() -> Result<()> {
    example1().await?;
    example2().await?;
    Ok(())
}

// Example of consuming `File` ... works great!
async fn example1() -> Result<()> {
    let mut file = get_file().await?;
    let mut contents = String::new();
    let _ = file.read_to_string(&mut contents).await?;
    println!("read {} characters", contents.len());
    Ok(())
}

// Example of consuming `Read` ... does not compile?
async fn example2() -> Result<()> {
    let mut read = get_read().await?;
    let mut contents = String::new();
    // ERROR:  `dyn async_std::io::Read` cannot be unpinned
    let _ = read.read_to_string(&mut contents).await?;
    println!("read {} characters", contents.len());
    Ok(())
}

async fn get_read() -> Result<Box<dyn Read>> {
    let file = get_file().await?;
    Ok(Box::new(file))
}

async fn get_file() -> Result<File> {
    let file = File::open("/etc/hosts").await?;
    Ok(file)
}
```

Comment: `Read` is a good way to go, yet using it in async context makes it by far more difficult

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pin:

```
async fn get_read() -> Result<Pin<Box<dyn Read>>> {
    let file = get_file().await?;
    Ok(Box::pin(file))
}
```

`Box<File>` (without `Pin`) works because File implements Unpin. `Box<dyn Read + Unpin>` would work too.